# Exclusion using java regex with more than one exclusion field

Tags: java, regex

Sorry guys, Ive googled and still cant get my code to work. Not exactly a whiz with java (yet, but give me time :-) ). I have an xml document that i am using a DOM parser to read, extract the class attributes and now i need to exclude some of those attributes using regex. For instance, my output so far is:

```
[[#text: ns1:Spare3]]

[[#text: ns1:Spare4]]

[[#text: ns1:Spare5]]

[[#text: ns1:Street]]

[[#text: ns1:Anything]]

[[#text: ns1:TearLineDateUpdated]]

[[#text: ns1:SourceReportTearline]]

[[#text: ns1:AnyFilter]]

[[#text: ns1:UpdatedByTelecom]]

[[#text: ns1:UpdatedByName]]
```

and i need to exclude those lines that contain the words `Spare`, or start with `TearLine` (not case sensitive) and a few others.

My code snippet (that i wrote to test with) says:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\Spare\\(.*?\\)",    
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher((nl.item(i)).toString());
if (m.matches())
{
System.out.println("["+nl.item(i)+"]" + "matched"); 
}
else
{
System.out.println("["+nl.item(i)+"]" + "not matched");     
}
```

How do i exclude any lines that contain the word `Spare` and any lines that start with `TearLine` (but `TearLine` can occur elsewhere in the word and thats ok).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those the actual strings you're trying to match?  That is, the DOM parser produced those strings, and now you're applying the regex to them?  If so, you want something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "ns1:(tearline|.*spare)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
);
Matcher m = p.matcher("");

String[] inputs = {
    "[[#text: ns1:Spare3]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:Spare4]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:Spare5]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:Street]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:Anything]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:TearLineDateUpdated]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:SourceReportTearline]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:AnyFilter]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:UpdatedByTelecom]]",
    "[[#text: ns1:UpdatedByName]]"
};

for (String s : inputs)
{
  System.out.printf( "%n%5b => %s%n", !m.reset(s).find(), s );
}
```

output:

```
false => [[#text: ns1:Spare3]]

false => [[#text: ns1:Spare4]]

false => [[#text: ns1:Spare5]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:Street]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:Anything]]

false => [[#text: ns1:TearLineDateUpdated]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:SourceReportTearline]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:AnyFilter]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:UpdatedByTelecom]]

 true => [[#text: ns1:UpdatedByName]]
```

Notes:

- I used `find()` instead of `matches()` so my regex only has to match the part that interests me, not the whole string.
- Some of the other responders used `^TearLine` because you said that word had to appear at the beginning of the line, but if my guess is right, you really want to match it right after the `ns1:` prefix.  On the other hand, `.*spare` allows `spare` to appear anywhere, not just at the beginning (`.*?spare` works, too).
- Similarly, Ωmega used `"\\bSpare\\b"` on the assumption that you were interested only in the *complete* word `Spare`.  I left out the word boundaries (`\b`) because you seem to want to match things like `Spare3` or (I'm guessing) `FooSpare`.
- I don't know why you added `\\(.*?\\)` to your regex, since there were no parentheses in your sample strings.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind using all those lines of code - just use this simple one liner based on `String.matches()`:

```
if (nl.item(i).toString().matches("(?i)(?s).*ns1:(spare|tearline).*")) {
    // not matched
else {
    // matched
}
```

fyi `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive and `(?s)` is the regex for `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
^(?:TearLine.*|.*\\bSpare\\b)
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to get rid of the first backslash

```
".*?Spare\\(.*?\\)"
```

because `\S` matches anything that's not whitespace.

For the other, your regex needs to look like:

```
"ns1:tearline.*"
```

Comment: (1) `TearLine`, not `tearline`; (2) `.*` is not needed at the end of pattern

Comment: @Ωmega He wants case insensitive, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

To match a line starting with TearLine:

```
^TearLine
```

To match lines containing Spare:

```
Spare
```

To combine those in one expression :

```
(?:^TearLine)|(?:Spare)
```

Comment: slashes are not anything related to regex. they are a perl language construct. lose them.